# Solving equation with square root of number with negative real and imaginary part

Tags: complex-numbers

How do I solve $w$ if I have an equation like this: $$\left(w-\frac{7i}2\right)^2=\frac{-25-36i}4$$

Normally I would continue with $$w-\frac{7i}2=\pm\frac{\sqrt{-25-36i}}2$$ but I dont know what to do with $\sqrt(-25-36i)$

Is it possible to rewrite $\sqrt{\frac{-25-36i}4}$ without $i$?

Comment: What has your question to do with [tag:calculus]?

Comment: Expand the square. Gather real parts and imaginary parts.

Answer (score 1):

How to render the square root of a complex number $z$:

$(|z|+z)^2=|z|^2+2z|z|+z^2=z(\overline{z}+2|z|+z)$

$(|z|+z)^2=2z(|z|+\Re(z))$

$\color{blue}{\sqrt{z}=\pm(|z|+z)/\sqrt{2(|z|+\Re(z))}}$

where the square root in the denominator is an ordinary real square root.

We can resolve the real and imaginary parts of this formula by rendering $z=\Re(z)+i\Im(z)$. This leads to

$\sqrt{z}=\pm\left(\dfrac{|z|+\Re(z)}{\sqrt{2(|z|+\Re(z))}}+i\dfrac{\Im(z)}{\sqrt{2(|z|+\Re(z))}}\right)$

We plug in

$|z|+\Re(z)=\sqrt{|z|+\Re(z)}\sqrt{|z|+\Re(z)}$

$\Im(z)=\sigma\sqrt{|z|^2-(\Re(z))^2}=\sigma\sqrt{|z|+\Re(z)}\sqrt{|z|-\Re(z)}$

$\sigma=+1\text{ if }\Im(z)\ge0, -1\text{ if }\Im(z)<0$

The sign factor $\sigma$ is based on the real square root being nonnegative, but the imaginary part could be negative.

Canceling the common factor of $\sqrt{|z|+\Re(z)}$ from the numerators and denominators gives the same formula as that from Paramanand Singh:

$\color{blue}{\sqrt{z}=\pm\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{|z|+\Re(z)}{2}}+i\sigma\sqrt{\dfrac{|z|-\Re(z)}{2}}\right)}$

For $z=-25-36i$ we compute $|z|=\sqrt{1921},\sigma=-1$ (the imaginary part of the radicand is negative), so

$\sqrt{-25-36i}=\pm\dfrac{(\sqrt{1921}-25-36i)}{\sqrt{2(\sqrt{1921}-25)}}$

$=\pm\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{\sqrt{1921}-25}{2}}-i\sqrt{\dfrac{\sqrt{1921}+25}{2}}\right)$

$\approx\pm(3.068-5.866i)$

Can you continue?

Answer (score 1):

Square root of a complex number can be calculated algebraically. One can equate real and imaginary parts in $$(x+iy) ^2=a+ib$$ to get $$x^2-y^2=a,2xy=b$$ and hence $$x^2+y^2=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$ Thus we get $$x=\pm\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+a}{2}}$$ and $$y=\pm\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}-a} {2}}$$ Note that the signs of $x, y$ are controlled by the equation $2xy=b$ so that they have same sign if $b>0$ and different sign if $b<0$.

For your question we have $$a+ib= - 25-36i$$ or $$a=-25,b=-36<0$$ and hence $$x=\pm\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{1921}-25} {2}},y=\mp\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{1921}+25}{2}}$$ and hence we have $$\sqrt {-25-36i}=\pm\left(\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt {1921}-25} {2}}-i\sqrt {\frac{\sqrt{1921}+25}{2}} \right)$$
You should try to remember the above technique more as a formula for square roots $$\sqrt{a+ib} =\pm\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+a}{2}}\pm i\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}-a}{2}}$$ and the signs on right side are same or different according as $b>0$ or $b<0$.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, to take the square root (or another root) of a complex number, write it in "polar form".  $\sqrt{re^{i\theta}}= \sqrt{r}e^{i\theta/2}$.

Here the complex number is $-25- 36i$. $$r= \sqrt{25^2+ 36^2}= \sqrt{625+ 1296}= \sqrt{1921}= 41.83 \space \text{approximately}$$  And $$\theta= \arctan (-36/-25)= \arctan(1.44)= 0.9638 $$

$$\text{That is}, -25- 36i= (41.83)e^{0.9638i}$$

So the square root is $$\sqrt{41.83}e^{0.9638i/2}= 6.467e^{0.4819i}= 6.467(0.8861+ 0.4635i)= 3+ 3i\space \text{(rounded)}$$

Comment: This is wrong on many levels. First off, the argument of $a+bi$ is not always $\tan^{-1}(b/a)$. The tangent of the argument is $b/a$, but the argument itself could be incremented by multiples of $\pi$. You have to consider the quadrant to get the true argument and thus the correct square root upon halving this argument. Then, the answer, already wrong because of the above, is rounded badly. The answer as written should be rounded to $6+3i$, the correct answer would instead round to $3-6i$.

Answer (score 0):

But I wouldn't take the square root at all.  The equation you want to solve is $\left(w- \frac{7i}{2}\right)^2= \frac{-25- 36i}{4}$.

I would do the indicated square to get
$w^2- 7iw- \frac{49}{4}= \frac{-25- 36i}{4}$
$w^2- 7iw- \frac{76+ 36i}{4}= 0$

Now solve that using the quadratic formula:
$w= \frac{7i\pm\sqrt{-49- 76+ 36i}}{2}$
$w= \frac{7i\pm\sqrt{-125+ 36i}}{2}$

Although that still involves taking the square root of a complex number.
Again, use the "polar form", $re^{i\theta}$.